# importing \Delta from mathdesign charter font

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, mathdesign, installing-fonts

Apologies for being a novice to the whole "selectively import symbols from other fonts" thing.

I'm trying to redefine \Delta so that it is the \Delta from the charter font from the mathdesign package.

I've searched up how to import a single symbol from other font, but I have absolutely no idea how to replicate what others did in my specific case.

I did successfully get fonttable to load up the exact symbol that I want though:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{mdbchr7m}
% there are a ton of .tff files in the mathdesign directory, and I found this one by trial and error
\end{document}
```

Upon display, it seems to me that the \Delta I am looking for corresponds to the first row second column of the table.

Any help will be appreciated, already spent hours on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First experiment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

$\Delta$ \texttt{\meaning\Delta}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now we know we have to find out what font is used for math group 6

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

$\Delta$ \texttt{\expandafter\string\the\textfont6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now we know all the needed details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\stDelta}{\Delta}% for the comparison

\DeclareSymbolFont{chartermath}{OML}{mdbch}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{chartermath}{"01}

\begin{document}

$\Delta$ versus $\stDelta$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure what's the reason for doing so much work.

Comment: Great answer, this indeed works for me!

May I ask for some more detail on the interpretation of the syntax here?

So from the first experiment, we see that \Delta is a math character (hence mathchar), what does "7601 mean? Does the 6 in the 2nd entry mean "math group 6", whatever that means?

For the 2nd one, iirc the output means encoding OML, family mdbch, series m, shape n, size 10, correct?

And for the third final prompt, what's the interpretation of the slots where you write chartermath and "01  and \mathalpha?

Comment: @tsjiang I'm afraid this would require a lecture on math symbol definitions, font selection scheme and a few other things.

Comment: got it, I'll spare you the lecture and find more info on these things myself. Already a search turned up https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf, which hopefully will be comprehensible to me. Appreciate you taking the time to help me out!